# React Native Cli or Expo Cli for Microprocessors bluetooth connection

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, native

I just started mobile project development and.I have to write mobile project using react.But i am confused.I don't know which cli ı have to use.Expo cli or react native cli.I have to connect electronical device's microprocessor.This connection works with Bluetooth and Wi-fi.I have to send data(on-off device or maybe timer) from mobile app to microprocessor.What should I choose? Expo cli or react native cli ? advantages and disadvantages on this topic?

Comment: I you wanna use expo (which makes the things over all easier) you can do that, but if you wanna use bluetooth you have to use config plugins (e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@config-plugins/react-native-ble-plx)